# Is there a way to use multiple filters on react-bootstrap-table2 table?

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-bootstrap-table

It is my first time using a new version of the react-bootstrap-table. I am trying to use multiple filters on some header columns. For example, I want the user to select one or more fruits or to search for fruit on the same column. The react-bootstrap-table2 has both filters, multiSelectFilter, and textFilter.

I couldn't find a way to combine those filters together. It looks like filter function only accepts one, not two or more. I would like to know if there is a way to do that. Thank you!

```
{
   dataField: "fruit",
   text: "Fruit",
   filter: multiSelectFilter({
     options: selectFruit
   }),
  filter: textFilter()            // A compiler will throw error since it doesn't accept dupilcated `filter`.
}...
```